# Задача: разбить названия фильмов из файла csv на отдельные слова и посчитайте все слова и кол-во их упоминаний

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть файл **`.csv`** со следующей структурой:

```
movieId, title, genres 

1,Toy Story (1995),Adventure|Animation|Children|Comedy|Fantasy, 
2,Jumanji (1995),Adventure|Children|Fantasy, 
3,Grumpier Old Men (1995),Comedy|Romance, 
4,Waiting to Exhale (1995),Comedy|Drama|Romance
```

Необходимо написать скрипт в Python, в котором разбить названия фильмов на отдельные слова и все эти слова посчитать.

Сейчас написан следующий код:

```
with open ('C:\file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        line_list = row.strip().split(',')
        line = line_list[1]
        line_1 = line.title().split()
        print(line_1)
```

Результат такой, дальше продвинуться не могу

```
['Title']
['Toy', 'Story', '(1995)']
['Jumanji', '(1995)']
['Grumpier', 'Old', 'Men', '(1995)']
['Waiting', 'To', 'Exhale', '(1995)']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это все довольно легко сделать с помощью pandas (я взял другой csv, потому что ваш - не показателен):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv("movies.csv", usecols=[1], squeeze=True)
res = s.str.replace(r"\(.+\)","", regex=True).str.extractall("(\S+)").reset_index()[0].value_counts().nlargest(10)
```

Заметьте, я удаляю указание года в названии фильма. Если этого делать не нужно, просто убираем `.replace(r"\(.+\)","", regex=True)`. Метод nlargest(10) показывает первые 10 наиболее часто встречающихся названий. Если нужно все показать, просто убираете этот метод.

res:

```
The       9
and       9
of        6
the       5
Love      4
You       4
in        4
a         3
Juliet    3
Day       3
```

Comment: strawdog, спасибо. Подскажите что в данном случае делает аргумент squeeze при чтении файла csv?

Comment: squeeze обращает полученную из csv-файла колонку в объект pandas Series. в противном случае мы бы получили объект pandas DataFrame, а это было бы излишним для наших целей.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
string = ''

with open ('file.csv', 'r') as f:
    for row in f:
        line_list = row.strip().split(',')
        string += f'{line_list[1]} ' 
        
print(f'\n{string}\n')


lst_no = ['.', ',', ':', '!', '"', "'", '[', ']', '-', '—', '(', ')'  ]   # и т.д.
lst = []

for word in string.lower().split():
    if not word in lst_no:
        _word = word 
        if word[-1] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[:-1]
        if word[0] in lst_no:
            _word = _word[1:] 
        lst.append(_word)

_dict = dict()
for word in lst:
    _dict[word] = _dict.get(word, 0) + 1

# сортируем словарь посредством формирования списка (значение, ключ)
_list = []
for key, value in _dict.items():
    _list.append((value, key))
    _list.sort(reverse=True)

# печатаем первые 10 самых используемых слов
print('Первые 10 самых используемых слов:')
for freq, word in _list[0:10]:
    print(f'{word:>10} -> {freq:>3}')
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Никак только не могу понять, зачем заново изобретать `Counter`, если он давно уже входит во вполне стандартный модуль `collections` %)